# Default constructor that creates an empty object of that class

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, constructor

I'm having issues understanding why this isn't working and how to solve it. I am trying to create an empty restaurantlist object in my constructor.

This is the problem below:

The RestaurantList class should be used to store all the Restaurant objects. This class should inherit from the LinkedList<
Restaurant> class.
The class needs to provide a default constructor that creates an empty RestaurantList object.

```
public class RestaurantList extends LinkedList<Restaurant> {

    //Default constructor
    public RestaurantList() {
        RestaurantList rList = new RestaurantList();
    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Subclassing a collection class is unusual. I'd advise against creating a `RestaurantList` class at all. Just use `LinkedList<Restaurant>`. No need for the subclass.

Comment: That's not a "default constructor" btw.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the constructor of RestaurantList within the constructor of ResturantList. This will end up in creating infinite calls to this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is referencing itself in the constructor.

An empty constructor would return an empty RestaurantList object.

```
public RestaurantList() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling the constructor inside the constructor. Every time you do that, you're creating a new stack frame, and since the stack is not endless, while your code is, you end up overflowing the stack.

There's no sense in calling `new RestaurantList()` inside the constructor. Maybe you've meant to call the parent constructor using `super()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just have a blank/empty constructor for RestaurantList(). Your implementation is currently recursive. Hence, the stackoverflow !

Thanks for the opportunity to answer about stackoverflow in Stackoverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a static method to provide an instance.

```java
   public class MyClass {
      ..
      ..
      public static MyClass getInstance() {
           return new MyClass();
      }
   }
```

You would call it thus:

```java
     MyClass mc = MyClass.getInstance();
```